# Javascript Split and Match the pattern array

Tags: javascript, arrays, pattern-matching

I am trying to get the pattern from a string in JavaScript, where my string is `01-01-2000 - 01-01-2010` here I want to make these both date separate like `date1 = 01-01-2000` and `date2 = 01-01-2010`.

I have tried this code **:**

```
var date = "01-01-2000 - 01-01-2010";
var date2 = date.match(/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/);
console.log(date2[0]);

output: 01-01-2000 [correct]
```

but I using `console.log(date2[1])` it displaying `01` only.

Please help how to achieve the goal make this function.

expecting output **:**

```
date[0]: 01-01-2000
date[1]: 01-01-2010
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a try to [`String.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) which returns an iterator of all results matching a string against a regular expression, including capturing groups.

Demo **:**

```js
var date = "01-01-2000 - 01-01-2010";
var date2 = [ ...date.matchAll(/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/g) ];

for (const match of date2) {
    console.log(match[0])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use split instead If your date format is fixed.

```js
var date = "01-01-2000 - 01-01-2010";
var date2 = date.split(" - ")
console.log(date2);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to work with pattern you only have to add the /g in the end for global search into the string:

```js
var date = "01-01-2000 - 01-01-2010";
var date2 = date.match(/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/g);
console.log(date2[0]);
console.log(date2[1]);
```